# Serve static files after decompression is operated on IIS

Tags: php, iis, handler

My issue is: I have files on the drive in a compressed format, I have to serve them decompressed.

today I call the converter with `exec($command,'2>&1',$sout,$sin)` each time the page is loaded, but due to increasing traffic this is becoming expensive. Now I want to convert files only "on the fly" so only if the specific link is requested nstead of decompressing those by default every time.

The issue is that I can't afford to hold all the data in uncompressed format on my server.

My idea was to write a handler that, given the `file.exp` request calls an handler that transforms 
`file.compr` into `file.exp` and serves this.

My Server is WS2012+IIS, my reference language is PHP.

Comment: Just a question: Is your disk space really at such a premium that you can't store the information decompressed?

Comment: The issue is I have to store thousands of audio recording per day, these are in gsm format to save space, but the user must be able to get them as PCM (customer request) and data must be available for at least 3 years.

Comment: I can see why that would cause a storage-based issue.  However, it seems like madness to constantly decompress the same content over and over again for a lack of storage.  You may find code review a better place to get an idea of the best way to achieve your aim?